# ASPX Page will only populate details from a specific AJAX call if user is in a specific Role

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASPX page which serves as a Manager Dashboard. The website uses Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication. There is also a custom Role Provider and a Site Map that specifies the Roles a user must be a member of to assess each page.

I have one AJAX call on the ASPX page that calls a WebMethod in the code behind, and it returns the JSON data I need to populate a bar chart and some pie charts. Users in the Admin role are able to view the chart.

I have another AJAX call on the ASPX page that calls a different WebMethod in the code behind, and it is only returning a successful response when the user is in the CCManager role. It then populates the contents of a div which allows the user to view and modify some data.

I cannot determine why this one AJAX call is not working when a user is not in the CCManager role, but is in the Admin role.

From F12 Developer Tools in IE, if a user is in an Admin role but not a CCManager role, an HTTP 500 is returned by this AJAX call:

```
responseText: "{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at Operator.GetAllOperatorAssignedAndQualifiedCategories()","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}"
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
function getOperatorDetails()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetOperatorDetails",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            operatorDetails = response.d;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

Here is the WebMethod from the code behind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<Operator> GetOperatorDetails()
{
    return Operator.GetAllOperatorAssignedAndQualifiedCategories();
}
```

The Manager Dashboard is in the Supervisor directory. Here in the Web.config, I have allowed the roles Admin and CCManager:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Supervisor">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,CCManager" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  ...
```

In the Sitemap, I have specified the CCManager and Admin roles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode roles="*">
      <siteMapNode title="Manager Dashboard" roles="CCManager,Admin" url="~/Supervisor/Dashboard.aspx" />
      ...
```

I cannot determine why this specific AJAX call is returning an HTTP 500 when the other AJAX call is working fine for users in the Admin role. The other AJAX call that is working fine for Admin users is virtually identical. Here it is for reference in case I am missing something:

```
function getCategoryImageCounts()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetCategoryImageCounts",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            categoryImageCounts = response.d;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error getting Category Image Counts: " + error.d);
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

And here is the WebMethod in the code behind that the AJAX call above references:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<CategoryImageCount> GetCategoryImageCounts()
{
    return CategoryImageCount.GetImageCountsForAllCategories();
}
```

Both the `CategoryImageCount` and `Operator` classes are located in the App_Code > Models folder. I have not included anything in the static methods of these classes that requires a user to be in a specific role, so I am at a complete loss as to why both AJAX calls are successful for users in the CCManager role, but for users in the Admin role, the call to `GetOperatorDetails` returns an HTTP 500 but the call to `GetCategoryImageCounts` is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually did not have anything to do with Authentication/Authorization. It had to do with stale data in the database when a user who was previously in a CCManager Role (and therefore also in a CCOperator Role) is removed from that Role. I needed to modify the `Operator.GetAllOperatorAssignedAndQualifiedCategories()` method so if there was data left behind from a user that was formerly a CCOperator, it would not try to insert that data into the `List<Operator>` returned by that method without first checking if the user was still in the CCOperator Role. Otherwise, it was trying to update properties on an object in the `List<Operator>` that did not exist in the `List<Operator>`.

Comment: I was just about to say, there's something screwy in Operator.GetAllOperatorAssignedAndQualifiedCategories(), probably not in the auth. Mark as answered when you can. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: It wasn't occurring in the dev environment. I had to retrace what happened in the environment that will be production (and I can't debug in), then finally got the same error to occur in dev.